# Why "User Removed" Affects the reputation of the user who has received the up-votes/down-votes by the user?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-users

I want to know why **"User deletion"** affects the reputation of user who has received upvotes and downvotes by **the user** , IMO it shouldn't affect the user.All the Ups & Downs **user** are done by him at the the particular time and correct state of mind, so they should be locked as permanent.

Also If any user who has major effect on your account suddenly gets removed you get in eyes of the **moderators** for **"Voting Irregularities"** Eg: this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5173426/user5173426) he had a good amount of rep but suddenly one of his follower decided to delete the account he got the account ban, it might be possible that someone had intentionally done it or one the follower might be a genuine one and decided to quit SO ?

I also want to know the difference between the *Voting irregularities* and *Serial Voting*

I am not advocating this user, I am just taking them as an example like what if really its not his fault.

Comment: So if we catch you using a sock-puppet to upvote yourself, you get to keep your ill-gotten gains. I think not.

Comment: See that issue is already handled by the "Voting Corrected"  - > https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed. I too agree on this that Sock-puppet is a real bad deal

Comment: There are voting irregularities not covered by serial voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the page [Serial-Voting-Reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), I got my answer.

> **What if I think I'm the victim of voting abuse?**
>
> If you see very unusual votes being targeted at your account, don't worry about it. You should wait at least 24 hours after noticing before becoming concerned, as the automated system should detect it and reverse it for you. If, after 24 hours, you do not see any fix to your reputation, please contact the team using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of any page.
>
> **Should I be concerned about these correction statements on my profile?**
>
> No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After all, we can't control the actions of other users. It's very rare where we'd run across a user who was intentionally using votes to manipulate their own reputation, and most cases you would have already been contacted separately if we thought that was the case. As long as you're not intentionally abusing the system to manipulate someone else's reputation or your own, you do not have to worry about such entries - they're just an indication that the system is doing its job.

Answer (score -6):

If a user is deleted, by default all of their votes are also invalidated. As far I know, mods or CM can delete user on a way which doesn't invalidate their votes, but it requires some extra clicks from them.<sup>1</sup> The probable reason is that user deletion is not a funny thing, typically there is some extraordinary behind it (for example, mods are deleting a voting/spamming sockpuppet).

In my experience, it is really annoying if sometimes I lose f.e. 40 rep because of a deleted account. But, as I can remember, I've lost maybe a hundred rep on this way, while I've collected around 30000 network-wide. Probably the SE tries to minimize the rep loss on this way. Yes, it is really annoying but it was not catastrophal.

Serial voting: if user X votes to the same person many times. It is obviously bad, because such votes are practically never vote for the content, but for the user.

Serial voting is one form of the voting irregularities. Another type is, for example, if a newly registered account votes all the posts of another user up. Yet another type is the "voting circle": many, anyways real accounts are voting eachother regularly up.

These all harm the voting database, i.e. they make not the really worthy content highly upvoted.

<sup>1</sup> Not being mod/CM it is not sure, but I am ready to hunt some references for ask.